# If General Reference becomes a close reason, add a field for an url like for duplicates

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, general-reference

Today, [Jeff said on the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/) that they are thinking to add a new close reason:

> **general reference:** this question is too basic; the answer is indexed in any number of general internet reference sources designed specifically to find that type of information.

If that does get implemented - and I hope it does - then please consider putting a field to enter an url like there is for duplicate questions. This way, we can close the question yet answer the user’s question so we don’t come across as elitists.

Comment: I second the “General Reference” close reason, and I also support this suggestion from Borror0.

Comment: Ohhhhh yessss. This is *great*

Comment: And please administer a mild electric shock to anyone who puts a LMGTFY link in this field.

Comment: Auto-suspend their account for 42 hours @Bill

Comment: @Bill: why mild?

Comment: @Tobias: It's for behavioral conditioning purposes only.  ;)

Comment: @TobiasKienzler To conserve electricity. Think of the planet!

Comment: And in cases where there's no URL (and no answer, I guess), maybe exclude it from indexing by Google et al?

Answer (score 6):

I agree with this in general; I don't think the general reference close reason should be deployed to all sites without such a barrier (closing as general reference should involve a little effort from the closer, so that it's not abused as “if you don't know this, you're stupid”).

Of course, just because a suitable link exists doesn't mean the question must necessarily be closed as general reference; [the link target should meet some important criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86043/introduce-a-general-reference-close-reason/101179#101179).

I have one reservation: there are occasionally cases where the general reference is not online, but should nonetheless be available to the asker. Even today, some software doesn't have its documentation online; “just look it up on the manual on your system, where it's clearly explained” should translate into a closure as general reference, even if no URL can be given. (Or maybe a `file://` URL?)

Comment: Or a command, like `man foo` or `help bar`? Especially the latter, since searching the whole manual for the documentation of common-word commands like `read` or `command` can be tedious.