# Why was this closed as "not a real question"?

Tags: discussion, not-a-real-question, general-reference

Was closing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152237/what-is-lwuit-light-weight-user-interface) the right thing to do?

The description reads

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

Personally I think it's quite clear what's being asked. Further more I can't see how it is ambiguous. It's definitely neither vague, incomplete nor overly broad. It's not the slightest "rhetorical". I definitely think it can be answered...

...actually it was *really easy* to answer. Perhaps that was the issue? People thought "why don't the guy google it for himself?" and just voted to close to "dismiss" it.

Is "*too simple*", or "*that's easy enough for you to find out yourself*" valid reasons for closing a question as *Not a real question*? If so, shouldn't the description be altered to reflect this?

Comment: Thanks for reminding me to vote on that question.  Done.

Comment: Now reopened for business.

Comment: Voted to close.

Comment: "This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, [and] overly broad" Which of those does it **not** qualify for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

we are experimenting with the "too trivial / general reference" close reason elsewhere on the network. The question you referenced is a good example of why.

[Introduce a  "general reference" close reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86043/introduce-a-general-reference-close-reason)

Comment: That's an interesting feature. Though I must say I agree with [Ninefingers answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86043/introduce-a-general-reference-close-reason/88520#88520). Take the question we're discussing right now for instance. 1) It would *definitely* have been closed (correctly) using this close reason. 2) Look at [the beautiful answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152237/what-is-lwuit-light-weight-user-interface-toolkit/6165904#6165904) that popped up 3 hours ago. I learned a lot from this question / answer, and so would someone googling for "what is lwuit".

Comment: I think it's still quite crap, but YMMV.

Answer (score 7):

It appears that people though *"Light Weight User Interface"* was being used in a generic way rather than referring to a specific product.

If that were the case, then the close would be fully justified.

As it stands, that reason does not make sense. On the other hand, the answer is a trivial google away:

[image: screen capture of google showing links to answers plus freehand circles]

So I am not sure it survives scrutiny anyway.

Comment: For the record: The original title of the question was *What is LWUIT(Light Weight User interface)?* so I hardly believe it was thought of as a generic question. *"...the answer is a trivial google away"* -- Right. So..... does that mean that you agree that it should be closed or not?

Comment: @aioobe: Possibly, if not for the close reason used. See [Introduce a “general reference” close reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86043/introduce-a-general-reference-close-reason) for a discussion around introducing a new close reason for just these kinds of questions.

Comment: Yep. *that* would be a valid close reason. So basically closing these ones as "not a real question" for the time being is the best option currently?

Comment: @aiboobe: Not in my opinion. I think these kinds of questions get closed (and downvoted) out of frustration with the OPs' laziness. They're *real* questions, but they're *really crappy* questions. I, personally, would like to see the "general reference" close reason added to SO, but in the meantime, I'm not voting to close. Downvoting though, that's reasonable.

Comment: @Michael Petrotta, +1 for *get closed (and downvoted) out of frustration*