# Does the question cap apply over all sites, or does it operate per site?

Tags: support

For instance, can I ask 4 questions here and 4 over at English, in the same day?

Comment: In fact, it seems that the limits (30 questions per month, 6 questions per day) are only used at Stack Overflow, Server Fault and Super User.
See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89241/183484) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95671/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's per site, so yes.