# Would questions about App Store approval be appropriate for SO?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, site-recommendation

I have a bag full of questions about common practices regarding submissions to the Apple AppStore approval team regarding OS X and iOS apps.

Would SO be an appropriate place to ask these? They are mostly rule-formulations and "red-tape" problematics, not as much technical problems.

If not, would the Apple.SE site be fitting for these?

Comment: From your description I would say "certainly not SO". I don't know of an SE where it would fit. Others might have better suggestions.

Comment: I don't believe there is _any_ SE site that will address these. Apple is the place to ask, they are the authority (and yes, them being so secretive is no help at all).

Comment: @Bart I would agree. SO is for questions directly about programming itself, as opposed to things related.

Comment: [ux.se] can help you with some of Apple's *published* Human Interface Guidelines and making an app have a suitable UX but app store approval itself isn't on topic.

Comment: Maybe try Ask Different http://apple.stackexchange.com/?as=1 But Apple's policies are not transparent, so you may have to discover by doing.

Comment: This is a similar question asked a little while ago: [where should I ask questions about submitting my app to the app store?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106008/where-should-i-ask-questions-about-submitting-my-app-to-the-app-store)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't think so.  I suggest you commit to [the App Stores proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/54103/app-stores) and help it become a site!

Comment: The proposal link is dead.. Its been deleted

Answer (score 8):

Beyond Matthew's suggestion about [backing the App Stores proposal on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores), most of the developers I know tend to gravitate toward the [Apple Developer Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/) for questions like this. They have a [specific forum for App Store questions](https://devforums.apple.com/community/ios/distribution/appstore) that is frequented by Apple engineers. The signal-to-noise ratio and overall traffic is lower than you'll find on Stack Overflow, but for now I'd say it's the most appropriate place to ask.

Answer (score 3):

Those questions would not be on topic for *Stack Overflow*, as they are not questions about programming, or (software) tools used by developers. By *questions about programming*, I mean questions about code to write, or a library/framework to use for a specific purpose.

*Ask Different* explicitly defines those questions as [off-topic](https://apple.stackexchange.com/faq#questions).

> and it is **not about** ...
>
> - Apple Developer Programs or iTunes Connect (including iAd and the iBookstore)
> - programming, with the exception of AppleScript and Automator