# Where to go for developer support specific to Android Market policies

Tags: support, site-recommendation, android

I am trying to find support for situations pertaining to publishing Android apps.

Recently I've had an app suspended from the market and after contacting Google multiple times and getting absolutely no where, I am left scratching my head and can't solve this problem.

I can't post a question like this on Stack because it's not a programming question nor can I post it on Android.stackexchange as thats for Android users not developers.

**Where can I find support for Android development and publishing when Google provides no direction?**

Comment: Isn't there a forum at http://developers.android.com?

Comment: You mean http://developer.android.com, @AlEverett.

Comment: @Michael: Ah, yes. Of course. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While this is not an exact duplicate of [Would questions about App Store approval be appropriate for SO?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131388/148672) since it's about a different app store, the answer to your question is pretty much the same.

Sorry it's off topic for any *current* SE site, but you should follow [Matthew Read's suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131389/148672)

> I suggest you commit to the [App Stores proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores) and help it become a site!