# My question was marked as off-topic, I believe it is not

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, off-topic

As we know, deployment is one phase of **program development**, according to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Software_development&section=1) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_deployment).

And as is mentioned in FAQ:

> Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to relate to programming or
>   software development within the scope defined in the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq).

and from [the SO FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions):

> Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people
>   who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow
>   questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question
>   generally covers …
>
> - *a specific programming problem*
> - *a software algorithm*
> - **software tools commonly used by programmers**
> - *practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession*

One of these tools is an online tool named **Chrome Web Store**. The duty of this tool is to help programmers deploy their software, and this is a tool that is commonly used by Chrome extension developers. So, **asking about problem with Chrome Web Store must be legal on Stack Overflow**.

I recently asked a question [How can I prove Google Chrome Web Store that I'm a developer and not a spammer in order to be able to publish my extenssions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312584/how-can-i-prove-google-chrome-webstore-that-im-a-developer-and-not-a-spammer/15315728?noredirect=1#comment21622586_15315728) but they closed it as off-topic, and said

> Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to relate to programming or
>   software development within the scope defined in the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Wasn't my question about software development?

Comment: There is a big problem here. Why downvote? Is this question off-topic here?

Comment: We are not an extension of Google's customer support team. Ask them.[

Comment: @JackManey This is meta, right? we can ask questions about questions ...

Comment: [Downvotes are different on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences), Mostafa.

Comment: Oh GOD! At last there is a place that let me ask questions!

Comment: Related: ["Would questions about App Store approval be appropriate for SO?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131388/would-questions-about-app-store-approval-be-appropriate-for-so) and ["Where to go for developer support specific to Android Market policies"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132742/where-to-go-for-developer-support-specific-to-android-market-policies). After some debate, questions about various app stores like this were decided to be off topic for Stack Overflow in general. There was an Area 51 proposal for a place to put these, but that hasn't gotten far.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First and foremost, I would like to make it clear that, to the best of my knowledge, **you** were not discriminated against on any basis when you posted [How can I prove Google Chrome Webstore that I'm a developer and not a spammer?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/44752/how-can-i-prove-google-chrome-webstore-that-im-a-developer-and-not-a-spammer) at Pro Webmasters.

As other answers here have stated, your **question** did not fit the guidelines applied by community moderation teams.

I am disappointed that you view the actions (to include my own) taken as part of moderating these sites in accordance with the guidelines set forth by the community as being racially (or politically) motivated.

We are here to help others, and (though I do not have an answer that would help you) I think you could find the answer you seek by visiting one of the many StackExchange chats (in particular, [Programmers](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard)) where programmers like yourself discuss topics which are not necessarily on-topic for traditional community Question and Answer pairings.

Comment: I'm sorry if I was impolite. If you were instead of me, you could see every thing in another way. I has been about a year that I'm trying to find a way to publish my extenssions, and still not luck

Comment: I can appreciate the hardship that this poses for you and I honestly hope that you find a resolution. My advice would be to consider your approach (it feels bad to be called a racist where one is trying to help in the same way it feels bad when it seems one is being discriminated against). That being said, you may need to try contacting Iranian expats and visiting sites which cater to Iranian companies to get the very specific assistance you need.

Answer (score 14):

No, your question has absolutely nothing to do with programming or software and everything to do with the relationship with the United States and your county, and Google's role in that relationship. This is a legal question for Google's support team. We cannot adequately answer it for you here and thus it is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm just asking for a way. not asking for a way to do payment

Comment: Like I said, it's a question for Google's support team. If they can't help you, try talking to a lawyer who is familiar with international law.

Comment: To pay a lawyer I have to bypass sanctions ;)

Answer (score 5):

Your question wasn't strictly about publishing a Chrome extension, it was more specifically about bypassing trade restrictions to get it published. This makes it off topic. Or at the very least too localised - take your pick.

Comment: I'm just asking for a way. not asking for a way to do payment or bypass sanctions

Answer (score 3):

I'm on the fence about this question.  It's an interesting problem, it's about deploying software to a web store, but it also happens to have a legal component to it.

It's not too localized, because too localized would be so specific to your situation that no one else on the Internet would have the problem. However, I'm sure there are other people in other countries who have this or a similar problem.

I'm leaning more towards reopening the question, and have cast a reopen vote. If there is a way to legally bypass these restrictions and verify your account, the answers on Stack Overflow could be useful to other developers in countries where their governments have caused the people to be restricted.

With that said, the arguments against reopening the question are sound, and this is a very borderline question. I encourage you to join the Programmers SE chat room to see if your post may have a home there, as this may likely be closed again even if it's reopened. Good luck! I hope you're able to find a solution!

Comment: Just curious, have you found anyone who would volunteer to pay the $5 on your behalf, sort of as a gift?  What does your extension do exactly?

Comment: I asked some programmers to pay this and instead I would work remotely, nobody acceptet. Currently I am developing some sort of stack exchange alarm. I have already developed some other axtenssions that due to this problem I left them away ... :(

Comment: @MostafaShahverdy - I'm not sure I'd be able to help in this manner, just for fear of violating the law in the US, but if you're building an extension for SE, consider hosting it on Github and then posting it on [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com).  It's not quite the same as the Chrome Web Store, but this is a good start. You'll definitely get some exposure. :) You should also contact Google on Google Groups and see if there is a way to get rid of the $5 fee for developers in your country. Hope this helps!

Comment: Installing chrome extenssions from outside of web store is nearly impossible

Comment: Actually, I was under the impression it was just a matter of dragging and dropping it in

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - Google decided that it needs to protect us from all the evil developers out there in the world because users are simply too ignorant and easily fooled into installing malicious software. While it's true you can drag and drop a downloaded crx into the extensions page, when you try to download a CRX, you get a warning telling you extensions can only be installed from inside the web store. Most regular users probably won't know how to install an extension.  However, Mostafa is developing an SE extension, which means most users will be like yourself, a power user and more.... :)