# Are questions about Apple review process on-topic?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Would questions about App Store approval be appropriate for SO?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131388/would-questions-about-app-store-approval-be-appropriate-for-so)

I am taking the following question as example, but I am referring to all questions similar to it: [iPhone App Review and SHA1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905161/iphone-app-review-and-sha1).

Are questions about the Apple review process on-topic for Stack Overflow?