# Why is this app store related question considered off topic?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, reopen-closed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Would questions about App Store approval be appropriate for SO?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131388/would-questions-about-app-store-approval-be-appropriate-for-so)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12817288

This question is on-topic and relevant in my opinion and judging by the number of helpful votes.  While app-store submission isn't really programming related, the question gets at what features you will have to implement in your program in order to meet the said goal.  Stack Overflow seems like the best place to ask this question since developers are likely to have run into issues with app store submission.

Answer (score 5):

> While app-store submission isn't really programming related

You nailed it right there, for the most part. Questions like this are less about programming and more about shipping a product to market.

Then, there's the 'market'.

Apple, and only Apple can tell you the authoritative answer to this type of question. Some people might be able to share trial and error that is sufficient enough for others to repeat their experience and success, but the process is bound to change at any time solely at Apple's discretion.

Programming languages and tools are not immutable by any means, but clearly published specifications, standards and documentation exist for them with very little ambiguity. They don't change on a whim.

This isn't specific to Apple, any 'app store' is perfectly free to change their policy overnight. We just can't keep up with that on Stack Overflow.

There is a [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores) for a SE site *just* to keep up with this stuff, you could consider lending your support to that.

Answer (score 4):

How Apple judges applications is not a programming question. Further, only an Apple employee can answer it reliably. If you want to know what Apple will accept, you really have to ask Apple.

Comment: The "not a programming question" is moot IMO; from the [faq]; "... but if your question generally covers … practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"

Comment: Programmers also buy sandwiches for lunch. And have boats. We've been through all this, I claim. But we'll see what other voices turn up.

Comment: Agreed Matt.  There are plenty of times I've had an IDE related question answered on SO that had nothing to do with programming, yet still was very relevant.

Comment: @Rosinante: *that are unique to the programming profession*?

Comment: Like I said, we'll see. Don't, also, forget my argument for 'not constructive'.

Answer (score -1):

My 2 cents;

I don't think it should have been closed as off-topic; the FAQ permits questions that are:

> ... practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession ...

Having said that, I think the question has already ran it's course ("Can I do this?... Yes you can"); there's nothing really that new answers can bring to the question, so there's no real *harm* in it being closed ("Too Localized"/ "Not Constructive"?).

Don't forget that just because a question has been closed, it doesn't mean it's deleted/ won't show up in search engines; people can still find it and benefit from it, they just can't add new answers (and I don't see why anyone needs to).

Comment: Eh... That's not really a good perspective in this case. If the topic is allowable, it should remain open - who knows, the correct answer may change over time, or someone may answer with new information. That said, I tend to think these are questions on Apple's inscrutable policies rather than programming or programming tools.