# Can I get two closed questions reviewed again?

Tags: support, closed-questions

I had four questions in a row closed. My last two happened at once in the [open-source](/questions/tagged/open-source) tag, and I've edited them but I think it's a dead horse as the title implies a legal question. But the ones before that, I think, were legitimate questions. I was just unclear and had not asked those kinds of questions before (app-store standards) and wrote them poorly.

I've edited these app-store questions:

- [methods of using uitableview that will pass app store acceptance [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15892030/methods-of-using-uitableview-that-will-pass-app-store-acceptance)
- [can mix use of a toolbar, change view, bring up action list, meet HIG's standards [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206343/can-mix-use-of-a-toolbar-change-view-bring-up-action-list-meet-higs-standard)

Can I get them reviewed/opened or further suggestions for edits? I've read people with a lot of reputation can do this but I am unclear who to contact or if this post could be enough to get them looked at.

Comment: One one of those there is a comment: *Please do not just describe your code or the approach, instead show us the actual code and the specific problem you're having.* and I notice you haven't followed that advice so I doubt that question will be reopened in its current form.

Comment: But they were design questions. Like can i use a toolbar to both control launching menu's and switch views was one of them. I don't need to understand how to program a toolbar but was trying to anticipate prior to app store submission if this was compliant with HIG.

Comment: Frankly, I can't even parse certain parts. "If i had a tableviewcontroller i could have a navigation bar at top and they customize in the table view and then hid done or back at top." I am at a loss. Obviously there are just some typos there, nothing serious, but *which* typos exactly? I edited your question, but couldn't fix that part. On a general note, do try to use proper punctuation, capitalization, etc. You have to compose the question anyway, so that's no extra time for you; for someone else, however, it means investing time that they could otherwise have spent on something else.

Comment: that table view question still might be hard to read. i will look at it again. I think my tool bar question at least now of the two is the easiest to read.

Comment: i've edited Methods of using uitableview that will pass app store acceptance [closed], and i think that one should be pretty clear now.

Comment: edited that one like 5 times. trying to strive for clarity. think it's  good now.

Comment: @LanternMike If you are asking design-related questions, I encourage you to explore [Programmers.SE].  This is a sister site to SO focused less on code and more on design.  The idea is the SO is about you in front of an IDE/Debugger and Programmers is about you in front of a whiteboard.  Please read the [FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq) first, but it might help with your issues of design questions getting closed.

Comment: I'll look at that. The second design question the answerer recommended i post in http://ux.stackexchange.com/ i'll look at both. From the second guy's answer and the negative response to the two questions i realized i had better places to ask. thanks again for the link.

Comment: I found stackoverflow because it kept coming up in my searches i made while programming. I got blinders and just posted everything on stack and didn't really explore the sister sites but i won't continue that.

Comment: while there may be a better fit else where, i thought all 4 of my questions fit the wiki definition of what can be asked in terms of "practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession", and that i just needed to reasonably scope them and hold out that some may be opened

Comment: the HIG is a practical part of IOS programming.  In stack overflow answers i saw comments for example like in one stack overflow post "oh and do not have a menu that launches another menu, it won't meet HIG, my first app i submitted was failed by that". The Apple standard doc is suppose to be considered in every choice of UI element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just editing your questions will result in them being place in a special "reopen review queue" in which users will have an opportunity to look over the questions and determine if the edits have addressed the problems with the post.

If you're really convinced that your edits have made the posts appropriate, and the post doesn't get reopened for quite some time afterwards, then you can consider flagging your post and informing the moderator through the flag that the question has been improved.  If they agree, they may reopen the question.

Comment: what would be a long time? one week? two weeks? and what would be the procedure for flagging them or link to doc on that?

Comment: @LanternMike I'd go with a day as long enough.  To flag the post click the `flag` link and just state that you've edited the post and think it should be reopened.

Answer (score 3):

These questions are not appropriate for SO, unfortunately.

Questions asking whether Apple will or will not accept a particular GUI design in the App Store are off-topic -- they are somewhere between business and UX, not coding. They also fall under the "not constructive" rubric: answering them usually involves speculation, anecdote, and back-and-forth comment chains.

On the other hand, if you have a *specific* and concrete UI feature you'd like to achieve via code -- "I am trying to create a table view whose top cell is fixed and acts as a button with a changing title" or something like that -- then your question will certainly be at home on SO (given, of course, that it also fits any other guidelines).

For further reading, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/175701 and [Would questions about App Store approval be appropriate for SO?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131388)

As suggested in the second one, support the [App Store.SE proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores) over on Area 51 if you think there should be a place for questions under this heading within the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: Do deleted questions count against the question ban more than closed? They have been deleted now.  It seems my last 4 questions fit in my mind as acceptable under the FAQ but were not.  I ask if they count more because i'm hoping to earn some points over time by answering and want to keep in mind where i stand.

Comment: @LanternMike - Deleted questions count against question bans, yes. While it's impossible to be certain due to the fact that the question ban algorithm is a secret, I suspect that deleted questions would count for at least as much as closed questions (all else being equal).

Comment: thanks for the answer. thats at best i thought that it is the same so that would be ok.

Comment: It's not 100% clear (intentionally) whether deletion itself counts towards a ban, @LanternMike, or whether posts simply count (vote-wise) whether they are deleted or not. The official public information on the ban is available at [What can I do when getting "Sorry we are no longer accepting questions/answers"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997) See particularly the heading "Are deleted posts taken into account too?", which links to a [post by Jeff Atwood](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86982/should-i-avoid-deleting-my-questions/87029#87029) with some information.

Comment: than you should i always assume that a closed question even without down votes would be a negative?

Comment: That's strongly implied by the FAQ to which I just linked you, yes, @LanternMike.

Comment: correct again, i'm a bit worn out on this. than you for your help.

Comment: Sure thing, @Lan, good luck.