# Clean up the App Store approval tags

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, burninate-request

It has already been established that [questions about app store approval are off topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131388/would-questions-about-app-store-approval-be-appropriate-for-so). Lots of these questions are along the lines of "Will Apple approve my app if...." and would be much better asked on the Apple support forums since most Stackoverflow users can only speculate what Apple would do.

There are a few existing tags which are about the app store approval process. All these questions should be either closed or re-tagged and the tags should be burninated.

[appstore-approval](/questions/tagged/appstore-approval) (511)
[appstore-approval-process](/questions/tagged/appstore-approval-process) (66)

There is also the [rejection](/questions/tagged/rejection) tag which seems to be almost completely about rejection from the Apple app store. This looks like it is a bit of a meta tag and could also be removed from any other questions which are not related to the app store.

Other tags which seem to attract theses types of questions, particularly when combined with apple related tags (ios, app-store, itunes, iphone, xcode), are:
[submission](/questions/tagged/submission)
[review](/questions/tagged/review)

[Questions which might need to be closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bappstore-approval-process%5D%20or%20%5Bappstore-approval%5D%20or%20%5Brejection%5D%20closed:no)

Comment: Definitely not all of them need to be closed as off-topic. I'd say a good third of them are actually about a coding/technical issue, or can be slightly rephrased to be.