# How do you treat (vote/close etc) questions that are really too simple?

Tags: discussion, questions

I came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12196214/include-one-php-file-in-another-php-file) just now.

*Edit: What should I have done with it?*

How should I deal with it? It is already at -13 (That's pretty much a record that I have seen btw) and has two close votes.

Now, I look at it, and it is a valid question, amazingly simple and the least amount of searching would have yielded the answer the OP asked.

I have looked at [Introduce a  "general reference" close reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86043/introduce-a-general-reference-close-reason) and I wonder how we should treat this before it is introduced (if it is).

Should I vote to close?

(It seems to be valid as in it fits the Q&A format, It's not Off-Topic, It *is* a real question (albeit a poor one), and it certainly isn't too localized). Who am I to say that this is too simple? I am sure that I have questions waiting to be asked that folks will look at and have the same reaction that I did - but what is the right SO thing to do here?

Should I leave it is is?

Added the question as it has been deleted:

---

How do I include a php file in another php file.. if the file to be added exists outside the folder?

e.g. I am working in A.php and want to include B.php in A.php...
the path of A.php is:  `C:\\wamp\www\Classes\NewClasses\A.php`
and the path of B.php is :  `C:\\wamp\www\Classes\B.php`

Now please help me how do I write the include statement to include B.php into A.php. Thanks

Comment: And it's closed.... :) There's your answer I guess. Though "not constructive" is a bit of a stretch.

Comment: I tend to vote as "not a real question".

Comment: @Bart Yeah, that was going to be pretty much inevitable - but if *I* see if before it is closed, what is the correct thing to do? What if a question that I ask seems trivial to the next person, should that be a reason to close it?

Comment: `It is a real question` No, it's not. It might be a real question in the sense that someone asked it, but it's not a real question in the Stack Exchange sense.

Comment: @YannisRizos So you are saying that I shold have voted to close?

Comment: @Fluffeh I would have, probably as NARQ. There was absolutely no effort / prior research evident in it, duplicating the manual is not what we are here to do.

Comment: In Stack Overflow's case they should probably always be closed as duplicates because you can bet someone else (or several hundred people) already asked and answered the same thing

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That question should have been closed as an exact duplicate (which I've done now).  Like many questions on Stack Overflow that seem too simple, this has [already been answered numerous times](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php%20include%20file%20from%20another%20folder).  I have no idea why this particular instance was downvoted into oblivion when others weren't.  I guess because in the original wording the OP was just asking for someone to do it for him.  Regardless, when you see a question that seems way too easy, odds are it's already here somewhere.  Please take a moment to see if you can find another copy to close the new question as a duplicate rather than just closing it as not a real question.

Comment: Why? Because PHP.

Answer (score 4):

The question should have been edited to be easier to read, not closed or deleted.

Who cares if people think it is 'too simple'?

From the FAQ:

> We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in
> them, but if your question generally covers …
>
> - a specific programming problem
> - a software algorithm
> - software tools commonly used by programmers
> - practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

There is no requirement for the question to be challenging to anyone. Also, one of the founding ideas of StackOverflow was to create a wiki-like repository for all software questions, not just questions that certain people feel are 'challenging'.

Comment: [**Do your homework** - Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Yannis: You are missing the entire point of that statement, and entire swaths of the point of this site.

Comment: @GEOCHET This is exactly what I mean - it seems trivial to anyone using PHP, that's one of the first things that any tutorial will show, but at the same time, it *is* one of he first things that any tutorial will show. What would have been the right action?

Comment: @Fluffeh: Did you not read my answer? And there is no 'trivial' question on a site devoted to being a repository of software questions. The idea is silly.

Comment: I disagree, partly, as more seasoned users we should first make the effort to provide a dupe and close it.

Comment: @GEOCHET I thought it *was* easy to read. It provided the information on what the user wanted, it gave enough information to be able to give an answer and it used syntax highlighting/formatting appropriately.

Comment: @Fluf: Then what was the problem? Answer it or move on. Or find a dupe which almost certainly exists...

Comment: Early on [Jeff wrote that no question was too simple](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/podcast-58/) and posted a [question about moving the turtle in logo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003841/how-do-i-move-the-turtle-in-logo) to make the point. Later he [changed his mind and that policy as well](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/). The official, from-on-high policy right now is that some questions *are* too simple.

Comment: @dmc: You say that like we should care what Jeff has to say about the issue.

Comment: End the end, that is up to you of course, but I have agreed with him much more often than not. Sometimes after initially disagreeing.

Comment: @dmc: Interesting since most of the time he doesn't agree with himself.