# Have the criteria for an acceptable question changed?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question

> **Possibly related:**
>
> [Introduce a “general reference” close reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86043/introduce-a-general-reference-close-reason)

I recently came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867916/creating-a-div-element-in-jquery) on SO. Here it is in its entirety:

> How do I create a div element in jQuery?

I think it is pretty evident that if someone were to ask this question today they would be thoroughly criticized for lack of research effort and directed to the documentation, even if their question wasn't a duplicate. Instead the question has garnered 200 upvotes and not a single close vote.

I understand that this is from a period earlier on in SO's history, but is every sufficiently broad question that is not a duplicate really welcome on the site?

Comment: The question is actually pretty good. The only reason I would use for closing such a question would be if it was a duplicate.

Comment: @EmilVikström Why is this a good question? I mean you could find this information from the most cursory examination of the documentation (both then and now), so what is the value of having it here, aside from increased Google traffic?

Comment: For the value, scroll down. The answers is where it's at.

Comment: @Bart The only essential part of the accepted answer is a fragment of the second code block 20 characters long. The rest pertains to selecting the parent, `append` vs `html` and a reiteration of the former, all of which are irrelevant. The only essential part of the most upvoted answer is this: "`Here it is in the Docs`". For the question asked, yes these are the best possible answers, but that doesn't count for much.

Comment: I'm not arguing that the question is good, nor that the answer couldn't have easily been found. All I'm saying is that it's not bad to keep it around because there is some decent info in the answers. If asked now, I'm pretty sure it would be shot down quite rapidly. But even so, the content is not completely without value.

Comment: @Bart I have to agree with that, to an extent.

Comment: Asad, I didn't read the docs before making my judgment here. Now I agree with you (it is the *first* page in the documentation). Sometimes features of a language or library are not that well described in the documentation. I thought the question was good because creating an element is a common thing people may want to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, to a degree.

We're a bit more strict about prior research, because Stack Overflow is much more popular now and the site would be flooded with basic questions otherwise.